# How to Trace Mobile App Install for share app ID across Apps?

Tags: facebook, installation

I've two apps sharing the same app ID for Andriod Facebook login, which i would like to advertise both apps in Facebook mobile app install using optimization for App Install and charged for App Install rather than Impression, but it seems that i can only fill in 1 bundle ID for that facebook apps, any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not reuse the same Facebook app ID for a second app.
One of the reasons is exactly what you are describing: you can only specify a single Android package name per app.